# How secure is BitLocker's "Encrypt Used Space Only" on a hard disk that was previously overwritten with zeros several times?

Tags: windows, encryption, bitlocker

I completely overwrote an older hard disk three times with zeros to completely remove data that was on it before. Now I want to use the disk with BitLocker, but I don't want to wait again until the encryption is finished. (I know that I can continue to use the hard disk during the encryption, but the performance suffers if I encrypt and write data at the same time.)

My real question is in the title of this post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BitLocker: Encrypting used space only or full space?](https://superuser.com/questions/1491409/bitlocker-encrypting-used-space-only-or-full-space)

Answer (score 0):

> How secure is BitLocker's “Encrypt Used Space Only” on a hard disk
>   that was previously overwritten with zeros several times?

It depends.

What information are you looking to protect, and from who / what?

Information I can imagine you being concerned about:

1. The data that was on the drive before
2. The data that you are putting on the drive now
3. Information about how much data is on the drive now

Information in category #1:

It isn't clear.  If this is a rotational drive, and if there are no bad sectors, then quite possibly this information is gone with the outside chance that the NSA or their counterparts can retrieve the media and do some hardcore analysis of the magnetic domains of the drive.  Otherwise, there is possibly some data preserved that could be recovered by less ... extreme ... adversaries.

Encrypting the whole media could help (only because overwriting with random data is likely to improve the efficacy of the overwriting with zeros), but won't hit the fundamental issues with bad sectors or portions of the SSD that are resting due to wear leveling.

Information in category #2:

This information is probably as safe as the Bitlocker keys and the least secure account password on the computer make it.

Information in category #3:

This information is exposed to anyone with access to your media.  This is really what you're exposing with the option to encrypt used space only, with the outside chance that an attacker who gets periodic access to the media can perform clever analysis on the media to determine useful metadata (e.g. how much you changed, and when) about the contents.

There is no question that encrypting the whole drive is more secure.  If you are protecting credit card numbers, you're done.  If you are protecting your diary from the NSA, you probably want to go a little farther; they are serious Nosy Nancys.